# Rate limit API in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rate-limiting

I am building an application based on spring boot. A requirement to protect the application is the API access rate limit.

I have read a lot of articles on this issue. However, it has not yet found a way to get started.

I have found bucket4j, redis, ratelimiter guava. Give me an opinion on the solution that you find it reasonable.

Thanks !

Comment: Try https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-zuul-rate-limit

Comment: @MadhuBhat Thanks. However, it seems that all routers must be listed in the configuration file

Comment: @MadhuBhat it seems that all routers must be listed in the configuration file. Can you help me ?